# Google Autofill Service for Android saves password under wrong domain

Tags: android, autofill, android-autofill-manager

I've developed a registration flow for my Android application that saves the new user's email address and password with the user's preferred Autofill Service. However, when using the Google Autofill Service that's part of Android O/P, the credentials are being saved under the wrong domain.

For example, let's say that my application's package name is `com.example.myapp`. When I call `AutofillManager.commit()` the save UI is correctly triggered. When I tap "Save", the credentials are saved to the "Passwords" section of the Google Autofill Service under the domain `myapp.example.com`. (I'm not sure where `myapp.example.com` is configured though -- it appears to just be the reverse of my package name which is not my actual login domain -- that's the problem).

I've used the Digital Asset Links feature to relate my app (`com.example.myapp`) to my actual login domain (`login.example2.com`) using  `delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds`. This `assetlinks.json` file validates correctly using Google's `assetlinks:check` API method.

So, how can I get the Google Autofill Service to save the credentials for each of the web domains listed in my `assetlinks.json` file? Is there an `autofillHint` for this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?